# Matching a substring to a string

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Please advise me on the following question:

I have two tables in an Oracle db, one that contains full numbers and the other that contains parts of them.

Table 1:

```
12323543451123
66542123345345
16654232423423
12534456353451
64565463345231
34534512312312
43534534534533
```

Table 2:

```
1232
6654212
166
1253445635
6456546
34534
435345
```

Could you please suggest a query that joins these two tables and shows the relation between 6456546 and 64565463345231, for example. The main thing is that Table 2 contains a lot more data than Table 1, and i need to find all the substrings from Table 2 that are not present in Table 1.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with t as (
  select 123 id from dual union all
  select 567 id from dual union all
  select 891 id from dual 
), t2 as (
  select 1112323 id from dual union all
  select 32567321 id from dual union all
  select 44891555 id from dual 
)
select t.id, t2.id
  from t, t2
 where t2.id||'' like '%'||t.id||'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `CONTAINS` operator like this :

```
SELECT * FROM Table2 JOIN Table1 ON Table1.id=Table2.id 
WHERE NOT CONTAINS (Table2.data, Table1.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are numbers from table two in a set place in table 1?  For example is the 1232 in the same place each time or do you have to search a sting for the numbers.  If it's set you could use an inline select or a temp table and create a substring of the string your searching and then join the table or temp table on that field.

Comment: The number from Table 2 is always in the beginning of a string in Table 1.

Answer (score 0):

you first need to say if the number in Table 1 and 2 are repeated, if is not then I think this query would help you:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table_1 
  JOIN Table_2 ON Table_1.ID = Table_2.ID
 WHERE Table_2.DATA LIKE Table_1.DATA
```

Comment: In Table 1 they are repeated, but in Table 2 there is only 1 record for each number.

Comment: then that query should help you